# Player position algorithm for cards game

Tags: card-games

So, in a classic 4 player cards game, which is multiplayer. I want to show each player sitting in the central position on their own respective screen. Opposite sitting players are partners.

```
      p2
  p1      p3
      p0
```

this configuration will work for first player.

For second player

```
      p3
  p2      p0
      p1
```

Is there a transformation (mathematical) that I can use to automatically find position. Or should I just make a hard coded lookup table, with manual entries.

Im hoping for a cool way to solve this. Matrices or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the coordinates of the four locations 
where the players can be displayed,
and just need to determine which player to show in which location,
number the locations $0, 1, 2, 3$ around the circle, starting from
the location where each player should appear on their own screen.

On the screen for player $n$, show player $m$ at position
number `(m - n + 4)%4`.

(The `+ 4` is to avoid applying `%` to a negative number in programming languages such as C++ or Java. It is not needed if you're programming in Python.)

---

[Initially-posted answer follows.]

If you wanted to compute the coordinates of each position directly,
one possibility is that the view of player $n$ 
shows player $m$ at the coordinates
\begin{align}
x &= x_0 - r \sin \left(\frac\pi2(m - n)\right) \\
y &= y_0 - r \cos \left(\frac\pi2(m - n)\right), \\
\end{align}
where $(x_0,y_0)$ is the center of the pattern and $r$ is the distance
from the center to each player.
This assumes $x$ is increasing to the right and
$y$ is increasing upward; if $y$ increases downward (as it does in
some computer graphics) then change the first $-$ to $+$
in the formula for $y$.

The matrix answer that you've already received is doing essentially
the same thing, if the scale of the picture is such
that $x_0 = y_0 = 0$ and $r = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will probably not use this because im not dealing with explicit coordinates. Only, predefined positions. Thanks again.

Comment: In that case, label the positions $0, 1, 2, 3$ around the circle, and put player $m$ at position `(m - n + 4)%4`.

Comment: i just plugged this in and it works. Thanks!

Comment: please add this to your answer so I can select it as one.

Answer (score 2):

Set $A_0=[0\ -1]^T$, $A_1=[-1\ \ 0]^T$, $A_2=[0\ \ 1]^T$, and $A_3=[1\ \ 0]^T$. Then from player $n$'s perspective, the position of player $m$ should be $\left[ \begin{matrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]^nA_m$.

Comment: brilliant! Thanks mate.